# Run a command using the subprocess.POpen module in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a cross platform way to run a command, wait for it to execute, and then return the output, error message (if any) and the return code

The following code works correctly on Windows

```
run(["start", "/wait", "msiexec", "/i", msi_file_name, "/q"])
```

but the same format refuses to run on Linux, unless I pass it like 1 string item in a list

```
run(["rpm -i {}".format(rpm_file_name)])
```

On Mac OS, the problems go further, for e.g., if I attempt to check a code sign

```
run(["codesign", "-dvv", binary_file_name])
```

it returns an error with help information and the command does not execute
and on attempting to call

```
run(["codesign -dvv".format(binary_file_name)])
```

the command does execute but the output is in the sd_err instead of std_out

Are there some flaws with my code, or is this some issue with the subprocess module? Is it advisable to call the subprocess module methods, i.e. pick either call, check_output, depending on the command and not attempt an unified approach as I am doing?

```
def run(command_to_run) -> tuple:
    """
    Runs a command on the shell
    :param command_to_run: The command to be run as a list or as a string
    :return: tuple with standard output, standard error and return code
    """
    command_as_str = " ".join(command_to_run) if isinstance(command_to_run, list) else command_to_run
    try:
        Logger.info("Running command {}".format(command_as_str))
        # Please provide a mechanism to run this on Windows without passing shell=True
        process = subprocess.Popen(command_to_run, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
        std_out = std_out.strip()
        std_err = std_err.strip()
        return_code = process.returncode
        Logger.info("Output: {}, Error:{}, Return Code:{}".format(std_out, std_err, return_code))
    except Exception as excp:
        Logger.error("Exception: {}, Arguments:{}".format(type(excp), excp.args))
        std_out, std_err = (type(excp).__name__, ''.join(excp.args))
        return_code = -1
    return std_out, std_err, return_code
```